# Calculation rules

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we have 
$$\begin{align}
  Y = X^2 \end{align}$$ 
and we want to isolate X, we'd just take the square root on both sides, such that $$\begin{align}
  \sqrt{Y} = X 
 \end{align}$$

But what if
   $$\begin{align} 
      Y = X^3                  
   \end{align}$$ 
How would you isolate the X here? Or even if the exponential is higer than 3?

Comment: $\sqrt[n]Y=X  $.

Comment: Be careful: $\pm \sqrt{Y} = X$

Comment: Read about [cube roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root) and [$n$th roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root).

Answer (score 6):

If $n$ is even, then we can isolate $X$ by taking the "nth root" of both sides:

$$Y = X^n \;\text{ means } \; \pm Y^{1/n} = (X^n)^{1/n} = X$$

If $n$ is odd, then $$Y = X^n \;\text{ means }\; Y^{1/n} = (X^n)^{1/n} = X$$

In each case, we can call $Y^{1/n}$ the $n$th root of $Y$, also denoted by $\sqrt[\large n] Y$.

Comment: You're right, @Austin. I replaced $\iff$ with text<

Comment: Could use another TU +1

Comment: Let's begin my day by salute my friends;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can do the same thing.  From $Y=X^3$ you can go to $X=Y^{\frac 13}=\sqrt[3]Y$  For even powers, you have the same sign ambiguity as for squares.

Comment: I think you want $X = Y^{1/3}$, not $Y = X^{1/3}$. (After all, we're given Y = X^3)$

Comment: @amWhy:  Oops, backwards.  Fixed